# Google docs sum by user

Tags: google-sheets

This is my table design:

dollar | Username

I wanna sum who gave me most money, so return Username and how much they gave me, I tried playing with SUM and EQ.

Really new at google docs, I would appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
=QUERY(E3:F;"select F, sum(E) group by F order by sum(E) desc";-1)
```